# Why is my route not loading my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react-router in my app for routing, where all of my routes work apart from the last one which is being used for modal purposes, however it's not loading the component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/veochorusapp">
      <ModalSwitch />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;

function ModalSwitch() {
  let location = useLocation();
  let background = location.state && location.state.background;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch location={background || location}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/applications" component={Applications} />
        <Route path="/waterType" component={WaterType} />
        <Route path="/feedType" component={FeedType} />
        <Route path="/products/:productName" component={Product} />
        <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
        <Route path="/interactive" component={ProductView} />
      </Switch>
      {background && <Route path="/feature/:id" children={<Modal />} />}
      {background && <Route path="/accessory/:id" children={<AccessoryModal />} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The route that is not loading the component is the following:

```
{background && <Route path="/accessory/:id" children={<AccessoryModal />} />}
```

The code that links to this route is as below. I have used the same process on a previous component which works perfectly.

```
function AccessoryBtns() {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <ul className="accessoryBtns">
      {AccessoriesData.map((i, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <Link
            key={i.id}
            className="btn"
            to={{
              pathname: `/accessory/${i.id}`,
              state: { background: location }
            }}
          >
            {i.name}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export function AccessoryModal() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let { id } = useParams();
  let accessory = AccessoriesData[parseInt(id, 10)];

  if (!accessory) return null;

  let back = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 text-right">
        Image
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h2>{accessory.name}</h2>
          <p>{accessory.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="backBtn" onClick={back}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} /></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Move them in switch.

Comment: What is the url equal to when the problem is happening?

Comment: Nicholas - I have a list of accessory links, that go to the respective url i.e. /accessory/1 /accessory/2 etc. but the AccessoryModal component doesn't load. I have the same process in place with the route above for features, which works absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you show us the code that links there? I'd like to make sure you're setting the background state correctly.

Comment: I've just added the code that links there

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks they are not inside `<Switch>`. Second, according to router docs, `children` must be a `function`

```
{background && <Route path="/feature/:id" children={() => <Modal />} />}
```

But since you pass no props to Modal you can simply use

```
{background && <Route path="/feature/:id">
  <Modal />
</Route>}
```

or

```
{background && <Route path="/feature/:id" component={Modal} />}
```

Comment: `First, it looks they are not inside <Switch>` Should they be? That would make them mutually exclusive with the other routes, and would force them to use the background location if it exists.  `according to router docs, children must be a function` That is incorrect; it *can* be a function, but it does not have to be. Your second code snippet is actually making use of this. Nesting components inside eachother is an implicit way of using the `children` prop, and what you passed in for `children` is `<Modal />`, the same thing they passed in in their code.

Comment: If this was helpful to you @Zak Faithfull and it solved your problem, why not mark it as the accepted answer?